# What am I doing wrong? "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am a newby at anything related to coding and was doing an exercise in a coding course. But I can't contact anyone there so I am doing so here. I am using Jupyter 6.0.1 from anaconda.

```
kingName = input("Hey king! Please type in your name at the prompt")  
numJewels = input("Hey"+kingName+",how many jewels are there?")    
costofEachJewel = input("Yo"+kingName+",how much does each jewels cost?")    
totalPrizeSize = costofEachJewel*numJewels
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2badf11c0f15> in <module>
----> 1 totalPrizeSize =costofEachJewel*numJewels

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast them into int, because the input are always string and you have to say to the program that the inputs are supposed to be integer (or floats if you want to allow floating numbers).

```
kingName = input("Hey king! Please type in your name at the prompt")
numJewels = int(input("Hey "+kingName+",how many jewels are there?"))
costofEachJewel = int(input("Yo"+kingName+",how much does each jewels cost?"))
totalPrizeSize = costofEachJewel*numJewels
```